# Stacked Column Chart Using Oxyplot and Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, charts, oxyplot

I've been using OxyPlot in my Xamarin.ios And Xamarin.Android projects to plot columns charts.This is how I've drawn the column chart using oxyplot.

Now I need a stacked column chart. I could't find it in the documentation. Is it possible with oxyplot? How? Any help is appreciated..

```
public class MeasurementGraph 
{

    public PlotModel VitalModel { get; set; }
    public VitalGraph graph { get; set; }

    public MeasurementGraph (VitalGraph graph)
    {
        this.graph = graph;
        var model = new PlotModel { Title = "" };
        model.PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyColors.Transparent;

        model.Axes.Add (GetXAxis ());
        model.Axes.Add (GetYAxis ());
        model.Series.Add (GetValueSeries ());

        if (Math.Abs (graph.trendStart) > float.Epsilon && Math.Abs (graph.trendEnd) > float.Epsilon)
            model.Series.Add (GetXtraSeries ());
            VitalModel = model;
        }

    CategoryAxis GetXAxis ()
    {
        int fontSize;
        if (Math.Abs (graph.trendStart) > float.Epsilon)
            fontSize = 6;
        else
            fontSize = 8;
        CategoryAxis categoryAxis = new CategoryAxis () {
            Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
            MinorTickSize = 0,
            MajorTickSize = 0,
            MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None,
            MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None,
            FontSize = fontSize,
            IsPanEnabled = false,
            IsZoomEnabled = false,
        };

        foreach (string day in graph.dayList)
            categoryAxis.ActualLabels.Add (day);
        return categoryAxis;
    }

    LinearAxis GetYAxis ()
    {
        List<float> valueList = graph.valueList.Select (x => float.Parse (x)).ToList ();
        float maxValue = valueList.Max ();

        float minValue = valueList.Max ();


            return new LinearAxis () {
                AxislineStyle = LineStyle.None,
                Position = AxisPosition.Left,
                MinorTickSize = 0,
                MajorTickSize = 0,
                MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
                MajorGridlineColor = OxyColor.Parse ("#f5f5f5"),
                MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None,
                Maximum = maxValue,
                Minimum = minValue,
                FontSize = 8,
                MajorStep = (maxValue - minValue) / 4,
                IsPanEnabled = false,
                IsZoomEnabled = false

            };
        }

        ColumnSeries GetValueSeries ()
        {
            var series = new ColumnSeries ();
            series.ColumnWidth = 50;
            for (int i = 0; i < graph.valueList.Count; i++) {
                series.Items.Add (new ColumnItem {
                    Value = double.Parse (graph.valueList [i]),
                    Color = OxyColor.Parse (graph.colorList [i])
                });
            }
            return series;
        }

        LineSeries GetXtraSeries ()
        {
            var series = new LineSeries {
                StrokeThickness = 2,
                MarkerType = MarkerType.None,
                MarkerSize = 4,
                MarkerStroke = OxyColors.White,
                MarkerStrokeThickness = 2,
                Color = OxyColors.Blue
            };
            int xStart = graph.vitalId == 20 ? 0 : -1;
            int xEnd = graph.vitalId == 20 ? graph.valueList.Count - 1 : graph.valueList.Count;

            series.Points.Add (new DataPoint (xStart, graph.trendStart));
            series.Points.Add (new DataPoint (xEnd, graph.trendEnd));
            return series;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tryed with 1 series per stacked column? I mean, you could overlap different column series, the higher ones behind the lower ones.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is adapted from one of their samples:

**MainPage:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App48"
             x:Class="App48.MainPage">

  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

  <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model}"></oxy:PlotView>

</ContentPage>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public PlotModel Model { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Model = new PlotModel();
        Model.LegendBorderThickness = 0;
        Model.LegendOrientation = LegendOrientation.Horizontal;
        Model.LegendPlacement = LegendPlacement.Outside;
        Model.LegendPosition = LegendPosition.BottomCenter;
        Model.Title = "Simple stacked model";
        var categoryAxis1 = new CategoryAxis();
        categoryAxis1.MinorStep = 1;
        categoryAxis1.Labels.Add("Category A");
        categoryAxis1.Labels.Add("Category B");
        categoryAxis1.Labels.Add("Category C");
        categoryAxis1.Labels.Add("Category D");
        Model.Axes.Add(categoryAxis1);
        var linearAxis1 = new LinearAxis();
        linearAxis1.AbsoluteMinimum = 0;
        linearAxis1.MaximumPadding = 0.06;
        linearAxis1.MinimumPadding = 0;
        Model.Axes.Add(linearAxis1);
        var columnSeries1 = new ColumnSeries();
        columnSeries1.IsStacked = true;
        columnSeries1.StrokeThickness = 1;
        columnSeries1.Title = "Series 1";
        columnSeries1.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(25));
        columnSeries1.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(137));
        columnSeries1.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(18));
        columnSeries1.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(40));
        Model.Series.Add(columnSeries1);
        var columnSeries2 = new ColumnSeries();
        columnSeries2.IsStacked = true;
        columnSeries2.StrokeThickness = 1;
        columnSeries2.Title = "Series 2";
        columnSeries2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(12));
        columnSeries2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(14));
        columnSeries2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(120));
        columnSeries2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(26));
        Model.Series.Add(columnSeries2);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What I wanted was two columns to appear stacked side by side. I added another column series without using .IsStacked = true, and I got what I was looking for. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: OK, glad you did it. Sorry if i misunderstood it, but **stacked column chart** has a very specific and unambiguous meaning when it comes to charting.